# Preg Match Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

What will the expression be for preg_match_all to get the content part of this string:

```
< meta itemprop="url" content="whatever content is here" >
```

So far I have tried:

```
preg_match_all('| < meta itemprop=/"url/" content=/"(.*?)/" > |',$input,$outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
<?php
$input = '< meta itemprop="url" content="whatever content is here" >';
preg_match_all('/content="(.*?)"/',$input,$outputArray);
print_r($outputArray);
?>
```

> Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => content="whatever content is here"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => whatever content is here
        )
)
```

*[Working Demo](https://eval.in/705785)*

**Edit**

If you want to fetch content of only `itemprop="url"`, modify regex to

```
preg_match_all('/itemprop="url".*content="(.*?)"/',$input,$outputArray);
```